# Linux swap partition created accidentally

Tags: hard-drive

While going through one of the tutorials for installing ubuntu I accidentally created a linux swap for drive D and was unable to undo the change. Now my drive does not appear in MyComputer but it shows in Disk Management. How to recover my D drive? 
Do I have to format it again, if so is there anyway I can have a backup of my files in D
Please help.

TIA

Comment: *"is there anyway I can have a backup of my files"* - Backups are meant to be created *before* you do something wrong, not afterwards.

Comment: Here's the tutorial for testdisk: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Answer (score 0):

Testdisk and photorec are your best chance of recovering data on a partition that you've formatted. Install using:
`sudo apt-get install testdisk -y`
and run the command
`sudo photorec`
The program is quite easy to use. Select the disk you want to recover data from (using the arrow keys and enter), then select the partition (Probably called Linux Swap in your case). Select "other" for the filesystem type. Then select a directory where you want the recovered files to go. After that leave it to recover what files it can find.

Comment: In general, running apt-get with the `-y` flag is not recommended as this may cause unwanted side effects (not for testdisk however).